# Vlookup with dynamic range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to create a macro to do `vlookup` for a number of columns from a file which is chosen by the user. Once I open the file I want to look for a certain column, and use the particular table range in the vlookup formula. However, I am getting the error `Application-defined or object-defined error`.

When I write this-

```
'Opening the file from which values will be looked up
st = Split(Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx"), Chr(92))
max = UBound(st)
fName = st(max) 'getting the filename
    
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)

'Find header column and last row 
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("ABC")
sht.Activate

ABCc = Cells.Find(What:="ColName", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False).Column
ABCr = Cells.Find(What:="ColName", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False).Row
ABClr = Cells(Rows.Count, ABCc).End(xlUp).Row

'Activating the workbook on which I want the value to be stored       
Workbooks("Destination.xlsm").Activate

Range("H2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],[" & fName & "]Sheet2!R4C7:R283C9,3,0)"
```

The above code works with out any errors but I want the range to be dynamic so I changed the last line like this-

```
    Set myrng = Range(Cells(ABCr, (ABCc - 3)), Cells(ABClr, ABCc))
    Range("H2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],[" & fName & "]Sheet2!" & myrng.Address(external:=True) & ",3,0)"
```

This throws me the error. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: `Address` returns `A1` -style by default, you're mixing that with `RC` notation.

Comment: Hint: use `Debug.Print`  and inspect the output in the Immediate Window, before attempting to write the formula to a cell.

Comment: and you do not want `external:=True` since you already included the filename and worksheet.

Comment: @BigBen Then do I just do `Range("H2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],[" & fName & "]Sheet2!" & myrng & ",3,0)"`

Comment: `myRng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`?

Comment: Thank you! It works :)